# Html select dropdownlist how to display name and id at the same time

Tags: javascript, html, loops, for-loop, fetch

I have been looking for same kind of question but did not find, What I want to achieve is, i want to display 'nama' and 'id' at the same time on option, so when one clicks dropdown list should show 'wick dhdfyj97' and 'abraham 15hndfj', is this possible (in javascript)? for now i have managed to display just 'nama'. This is how my json looks like :

```
[{"nama ": "wick","id": "dhdfyj97",},{"nama ": "abraham","id": "15hndfj",}]
```

Here is the code :

```html
 .then(res =>{ 
    res.json().then(num => {
 
for (var o = 0; o < num.length; o++) {
    var i = document.getElementById("Select");
    var d = document.createElement("option");
    d.text = num[o].nama;
 
    i.add(d);
}
    }
  )
   })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can add both using string literals.

```
 .then(res =>{ 
    res.json().then(num => {
       for (var o = 0; o < num.length; o++) {
            var i = document.getElementById("Select");
            var d = document.createElement("option");
            d.text = `${num[o].nama} ${num[o].id}`;

           i.add(d);
       }
    }
   )
 })
```

i would also suggest to query for the html tag only once and reuse it, also iterate through the response directly using for of loop:

```
const i = document.getElementById("Select");
for (const item of num) {        
    const d = document.createElement("option");
    d.text = `${item.nama} ${item.id}`;
    i.add(d);
}
```

you can learn more about template literals here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals
you can refer MDN for much more.

Answer (score 0):

Concatenate the nama and the id together:

```html
 .then(res =>{ 
    res.json().then(num => {
 
for (var o = 0; o < num.length; o++) {
    var i = document.getElementById("Select");
    var d = document.createElement("option");
    d.text = num[o].nama + ' ' + num[o].id;
 
    i.add(d);
}
    }
  )
   })
```

Answer (score 0):

Create an Option tag and  assign its `textContent` to concatenation of `item.nama` and `item.id` and append it to the `Select` tag,
also you see the space in `"nama "` remove that,so it should be `"nama"` instead otherwise it's going to show undefined in the `option` tag

```js
let Array = [
    { "nama": "wick", id: "dhdfyj97" },
    { "nama": "abraham", id: "15hndfj" },
  ];
  let Select = document.getElementById("Select");
  Array.map((item) => {
    var d = document.createElement("option");
    d.textContent = item.nama + " " + item.id;
    Select.appendChild(d);
  });
```

```html
<select id="Select"> </select>
```